# Grafana - Build a Panel Plugin from Template - Error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, grafana, grafana-templating

I am currently in the process of creating a new panel plugin by following the tutorial located here: [Create Plugin](https://github.com/grafana/plugin-tools/tree/main/packages/create-plugin) and here [Build your first plugin](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/developers/plugins/create-a-grafana-plugin/develop-a-plugin/build-a-panel-plugin/).

Steps I followed in accordance with the tutorial:

`npm init @grafana/plugin`

selected panel type, name, description and so on...

```
npm i

npm run dev
```

**I got an error by npm run dev:**

```
ERROR in ./module.ts
Module build failed (from ../node_modules/swc-loader/src/index.js):
Error: failed to handle: base_dir(./src) must be absolute. Please ensure that `jsc.baseUrl` is specified correctly.

webpack 5.88.2 compiled with 1 error in 330 ms
Type-checking in progress...
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'base_dir(./src) must be absolute. Please ensure that `jsc.baseUrl` is specified correctly.', /usr/local/cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/swc_ecma_transforms_module-0.173.28/src/path.rs:104:13
assets by status 17.1 KiB [cached] 6 assets
./module.ts 39 bytes [built] [1 error]

ERROR in ./module.ts
Module build failed (from ../node_modules/swc-loader/src/index.js):
Error: failed to handle: base_dir(./src) must be absolute. Please ensure that `jsc.baseUrl` is specified correctly.
```

Can someone provide assistance? I expected it to work smoothly since the instructions are directly from Grafana, and I am following the prescribed steps. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,
Marcelo

Comment: I set baseUrl from "./" to "/" and it's fixed.

Answer (score 4):

There's an open [issue](https://github.com/grafana/plugin-tools/issues/344) in `grafana/plugin-tools` related to this bug.

The `@swc/core` is bugged in version 1.3.76 (there's a fix that has been merged but not released yet).

On my side downgrading this package to 1.3.75 fixed this error

In the `package.json` you can downgrade the `@swc/core` to version to 1.3.75 like this:

```
"@swc/core": "1.3.75"
```

And run a `yarn install` again

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution did not help me, but the Grafana team figured it out, and it is working now.